# ArcGIS add features (Feature Service) does not load map in Android

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime

I published the service using ArcGIS Server and can load it successfully with JS API.

```
var layerss = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://hbsyb.booway.com.cn/arcgis/rest/services/zjsxyd/sichuanxianjixingzhengqu/MapServer/0",
    outFields : ["*"],
    opacity : 0.5
});
map.add(layerss);
```

When I want to load it with Android Runtime Sdk 100.15.0(FeatureLayer), it doesn't work.

```
final ServiceFeatureTable serviceFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("https://hbsyb.booway.com.cn/arcgis/rest/services/zjsxyd/sichuanxianjixingzhengqu/MapServer/0");

final FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(serviceFeatureTable);
featureLayer.setSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);
featureLayer.setSelectionWidth(10);
map.getOperationalLayers().add(featureLayer);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi please help me

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesn't work'...?    Do you get an error message/traceback? Do you have logs of runtime? Is there a map interface that isn't showing the layer. Please provide some more detail other than 'it doesn't work'.